# Undefined $input in kohana

Tags: input, kohana, undefined

So..I've created a controller inside a directory.

```
application
  - classes
      - controller
          - api
              user.php
```

and added the following route in my bootstrap

```
Route::set('with_dir','api/(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')->defaults(array(
    'directory'=>'api',
    'controller'=>'index'
));
```

I can access my user controller by /api/user, but the problem is that I get the following error.

```
Undefined property: Controller_Api_User::$input
```

in my user controller, I have

```
$fbid = $this->input->post('fbid');
```

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best bet? You followed a 2.x tut while you use 3.x. Try $this->request->post('fbid');

You can find the api docs here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api

Comment: // exaclty. just found out that there's no input class in ko3. Thanks!